# How come jmap -live triggers a GC while it never triggers in the application itself?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

We are running the java application that is used as supervision system intended to run 24/7. We had some memory issues so I've made a jmap dump that I can analyze it. After I made the second dump with live flag, the GC was ran in the application also and it's memory usage was low again (the process is running for 6 months now). So my question is how come the GC wasn't run by the process itself in the meantime if then after the jmap dump it could perform a GC, the process was running normally after that and it's memory usage was ok?

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1) is the version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The "live" option forces a full collection, which then also attempts to shrink the total amount of memory reserved for the heap. Automatic GC avoids performing full collections, and so the reserved memory won't necessarily go down. The exact behavior varies by which GC you're using (G1 is the default) and any additional settings you may have provided.